# Can't override user agent stylesheet coloring my links

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, stylesheet

It's always these simple problems that snag me.

I have a very simple page I'm building, and I want the hyperlinks to not be colored specially at all (not blue originally, not purple for visited) or underlined.

I've done this in other sites before without issue simply by using

```
a, a:visited, a:hover, a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: none;
}
```

However, in this particular site, that's not doing the trick for the color, while the underline is successfully removed. I even tried adding the dreaded `!important` tag, with no effect.

This issue has been seen on Chrome, IE 11, and Android (WebView).

When I inspect the links using Chrome's Developer console, it's pulling its `color` attribute from the `user agent stylesheet`, specifically:

```
a:-webkit-any-link {
    color: -webkit-link;
}
```

So I tried overriding this explicitly in my stylesheet by adding `a:-webkit-any-link` to my list of tags to apply the `color: none` attribute to, again, to no effect. I also added `a:any-link` and `a:link` in various combinations, to no avail.

Thoughts on the obvious solution I'm overlooking?

Comment: `color: none;` is invalid, it has to be a valid color name string, rgb or hex code.

Comment: how could you think of which color it should be when using `color:none`? the default color of a link should be close to `blue`, of a text should be close to `black`...

Comment: Like the other guys have said, you need to specify the color, you can't use color: none as that makes no sense at all. You would need to use color: #fff; or color: #000; I hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As the comments said `color:none;` is not valid css.

This should work:

```
a, a:visited, a:hover, a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}
```